# Approximation of the product $(\bar{z} - a)^{-1} \cdot (z - b)^{-1}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, power-series

$\def\zbar{\smash{\overline z}\vphantom z}$I would like to construct an approximation of the product
\begin{equation}
f(z) = \frac{1}{\zbar-a} \frac{1}{z-b},
\end{equation}
where $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$, and $|{a}/{z}|, |{b}/{z}| <1$.

More precisely, I would like to obtain a separable expression of the form:
\begin{equation}
f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty g_k(a,b) h_k(z, \overline{z}),
\end{equation}
where $g_k$ depends only on $a$ and $b$, and $h_k$ depends only on $z$ and $\overline{z}$. We can rewrite the product $f(z)$ as a double sum:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\zbar-a} \frac{1}{z-b}  = \frac{1}{|z|^2}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a}{\overline{z}}\right)^j \right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{b}{z}\right)^k \right) = \frac{1}{|z|^2} \sum_{j,\;k} \left(\frac{a}{\overline{z}}\right)^j \left(\frac{b}{z}\right)^k.
\end{equation}

Unfortunately, the function $f$ is not analytic so we cannot use a [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) to obtain the desired form.

**Question:** Is there a technique to obtain the desired factorization of $f$ when $|{a}/{z}|, |{b}/{z}| <1$?

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted, with $h_{jk}=\overline{z}^{-j-1}z^{-k-1}$, $g_{jk}=a^jb^k$ and if desired, you can label the $(j,k)$ by a single index.

Comment: Cauchy product has to do with convergence, not with analyticity.

Comment: @Christian Remling, thank you for your answer. I am not sure that I understand your point. How do you define $g_k$ and $h_k$ to only have one infinite sum.

Comment: For instance, if we look at $(z - a)^{-1} \cdot (z - b)^{-1}$, then we can define $g_k(a,b) = \sum_{l=0}^k a^l b^{k-l}$, and $h_k(a,b) = z^{-k-2}$ to obtain the desired factorization. I am looking for a similar decomposition for $(\bar{z} - a)^{-1} \cdot (z - b)^{-1}$.

Comment: I understand @ChristianRemling to mean the following: Define, e.g., the sequence $(j,k)=(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(1,1),(2,0),(0,3),(1,2),(2,1),(3,0),(0,4),...$ and sum over the terms $g_{jk} h_{jk} $ according to that sequence ...

Comment: Yes, what Michael explained is what I had in mind: use a bijection $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N^2$ to label the $g,h$ by a single index if desired.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Late TeX note: $\displaystyle\frac1{\overline z - a}\frac1{z - b}$ looks strange, because the adjacent denominators don't line up.  I edited to $\dfrac1{\smash{\overline z}\vphantom z - a}\dfrac1{z - b}$ `\frac1{\smash{\overline z}\vphantom z - a}\frac1{z - b}` (where probably the `\vphantom z` is unnecessary, but harmless, to make sure that the enclosed material has at least the height of the $z$).  If the overline is too close to the fraction bar, then you can also use $\dfrac1{\overline z - a}\dfrac1{z\vphantom{\overline z} - b}$ `\frac1{\overline z - a}\frac1{z\vphantom{\overline z} - b}`.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

I am interested in forming a factorization for $f(z) = ({\bar{z} -a})^{-1} \cdot ({z -b}^{-1})$ of the following form
\begin{equation}
f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty g_k(a,b) h_k(z, \overline{z}),
\end{equation}
where $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$, $|{a}/{z}|, |{b}/{z}| <1$, $g_k$ depends only on $a$ and $b$, and $h_k$ depends only on $z$ and $\overline{z}$. We can rewrite the product $f(z)$ as a double sum:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\overline{z}-a} \frac{1}{z-b}  = \frac{1}{|z|^2}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a}{\overline{z}}\right)^j \right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{b}{z}\right)^k \right) = \frac{1}{|z|^2} \sum_{j,\;k} \left(\frac{a}{\overline{z}}\right)^j \left(\frac{b}{z}\right)^k.
\end{equation}

To obtain the desired factorization for $f$, we use a bijection from $\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$, such bijection exists because $\mathbb{N}^2$ is countable. For instance, we can use the Cantor pairing $\sigma$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) given by:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sigma \; \colon \; & \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N},\\ & (j,  k) \mapsto \sigma(j,k) = \frac{1}{2}(j+k)(j+k+1)+k.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The inverse of the Cantor pairing is denoted $\sigma^{-1}$. Let define $g_{j,k}(a,b) = a^j b^k$, and $h_{j,k}(z, \bar{z}) = \bar{z}^{-j-1} z^{-k-1}$ for $j, k\in \mathbb{N}$. The desired factorization is given by
\begin{equation}
f(z) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty g_{\sigma^{-1}(l)}(a,b)h_{\sigma^{-1}(l)}(z,\bar{z}).
\end{equation}